# Unsure of attempt to determine $\dim(W_1+W_2)$ and $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^4$. $W_1$ is a subspace of $V$ spanned by vectors $a_1=(1, 2, 0, 1)$ and $a_2=(1,1,1,0)$. $W_2$ is a subspace of $V$ spanned by vectors $b_1=(1,0,1,0)$ and $b_2=(1,3,0,1)$. Determine $\dim(W_1+W_2)$ and $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$.

**Attempt**
The vectors $a_1$ and $a_2$ are linearly independent and span $W_1$, so they form a basis for $W_1$. Hence $\dim(W_1)=2$. The vectors $b_1$ and $b_2$ are linearly independent and span $W_2$, so they form a basis for $W_2$. Hence $\dim(W_2)=2$.

This is the step that I'm unsure of. I added vectors from $W_1$ and $W_2$ together, i.e. $a_1 + b_1, a_1 + b_2, a_2 + b_1, a_2 + b_2$ to form $$W_1+W_2=\left\{(2,2,1,1),(2,5,0,2),(2,1,2,0),(2,4,1,1) \right\}.$$

The first three vectors are linearly independent, but $$(2,4,1,1)= (2,5,0,2)+(2,1,2,0)-(2,2,1,1).$$ Hence there are only $3$ vectors that are linearly independent and span $W_1+W_2$, so $\dim(W_1+W_2)=3$.

We know that $\dim(W_1+W_2) = \dim(W_1) + \dim (W_2) - \dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$. Therefore $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2)=2+2-3=1$.

**Question**
Is my attempt correct?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Everything is fine, although I would make it clear that $W_1+W_2$ is the set **spanned** by those four vectors, not just the set that **is** those four vectors. Also, again being picky, instead of saying "there are only $3$ vectors that are linearly independent and span $W_1+W_2$", you should say that "There is a basis of $W_1+W_2$ consisting of three vectors. You've certainly got the right method though.

Comment: @TomOldfield Thank you for your comment.

Comment: No worries, hope it helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt is correct, but note that your understanding of $W_1 + W_2$ might be wrong. By definition, $W_1 + W_2 = \{\vec{w}_1 + \vec{w}_2 | \vec{w}_i \in W_i, i=1, 2\}.$ However, This doesn't mean that the bases have to be added together. In other words, you can simply take $\{a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2\}$ as a spanning set for the space $W_1 + W_2$ and then toss out any linearly dependent vectors. The easiest way to do this is to row reduce the matrix whose columns are the corresponding basis vectors. For your example, the matrix will row reduce to (why? -- try it!)
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
This tells you that you have three linearly independent vectors and so the dimension of the $W_1 + W_2$ is 3.

Edit: another related question  that is useful to ask yourself: if $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$ are linearly independent, are $a_1 + a_2, a_1 - a_2, a_3 + a_4, a_3 - a_4$? How would you check? (hint: checking independence can always be reduced to row reducing a matrix)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I added the vectors from $W_1$ and $W_2$ because of the definition $W_1 + W_2 = \{\vec{w}_1 + \vec{w}_2 | \vec{w}_i \in W_i, i=1, 2\}$. Could you please explain why I can simply take $\{a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2\}$ as a spanning set for $W_1 + W_2$?

Comment: Sure. I'll avoid the \vec signs. Any $w_1 \in W_1$ is a linear combination of $a_1$ and $a_2$, same for $b_1, b_2$. Thus, to say that you take any $w_1 \in W_1$ is to say that you can take $c_1a_1 + c_2 a_2$ for any scalars $c_1, c_2$, same for $W_2$. As such, $\{w_1 + w_2 | w_i \in W_i\} = \{c_1 a_1 + c_2 a_2 + d_1 b_1 + d_2 b_2 | c_i, d_i \in \mathbb{R}\} = \mathrm{span}(a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2)$. Intuitively, I just need to be able to get any vector in $W_1$ and any vector in $W_2$, then add them together. To do that, I just need basis vectors from both spaces, and those may overlap. Clear?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: @user4167: Here's another way to see it. Since $\vec 0\in W_1,W_2$, it follows that $W_1,W_2\subseteq W_1+W_2$. In fact, $W_1+W_2$ is the **smallest** subspace of $V$ containing $W_1,W_2$. (Why?) Thus, if we have given bases (or even just spanning sets) $B_1,B_2$ for $W_1,W_2$ respectively, then $B_1\cup B_2$ will be a spanning set (though not necessarily a basis) for $W_1+W_2$.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thank you for your explanation. It really helps!